# What does pass on mean either move on/proceed or politely declined in the quoted sentences?

Tags: meaning

I want to know whether the meaning of **pass on** is move on /proceed the idea in the future,even though, it is not interested to follow now  or politely declined the idea also in the future as mentioned in the quoted sentences:"The idea is interesting, but unfortunately it doesn’t match what we’re currently looking to fund or distribute. Therefore, we’ll have to **pass on** the opportunity to consider it further."

Answer (score 2):

**Pass on** can have several meanings: to continue moving forwards, to pass a message to another person, or a euphemism for 'to die'. However, what I think is meant here is a usage of **pass** which seems to have originated with the long-running BBC TV quiz *Mastermind*, in which contestants have to answer as many questions as possible in a limited time. To save time they say 'pass' if they cannot answer a question, and the usage has spread to other quizzes and to general use. I think the organisation is saying "We have to say 'pass' on the opportunity", in other words, decline to consider it.

Answer (score 1):

To pass on something — with the stress on *pass* rather than *on* — comes from cardplaying or other games where, if one can't or doesn't wish to play, one *passes*, usually by saying "Pass," so the next player knows it's his/her turn to play. [See meaning 52.](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/pass?s=t) All other meanings place the stress on *on*.

This meaning has spread to almost any context: "Would you like some of Aunt Hilda's deep-fried broccoli?" "No thanks, I'll pass." I could then say I passed on Aunt Hilda's deep-fried broccoli or I gave it a pass.

So like Aunt Hilda's broccoli, those from whom you sought funding found your idea interesting, but they've decided to pass on the opportunity, i. e., they're not biting.